# Route user to Safari to make PayPal Payment

Tags: ios, paypal, safari, payment

I originally implemented the PayPal SDK for in-app payments, but need to process some payments outside of my app (in Safari) due to an App Store rule.

How can I route a user to a PayPal Express mobile checkout in Safari, and then bring them back to my app after the payment is made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Express Checkout Digital Goods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/)?  Express Checkout alone will automatically use a mobile experience in the browser when it recognizes a mobile device.  Then you could just make a few adjustments (if you want to) so that it works with a lightbox/pop-up window on top of your app.